# Django dynamic url. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-queryset

So I have this URL scheme:

```
(r'^test/(?P<name>\d+)/', 'test'),

def test(request, name):
    html = "it worked"
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

however, when I go to the following URL, I get a 404 error:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/words/`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant to use `\w` instead, e.g.:

```
(r'^test/(?P<name>\w+)/', 'test'),
```

`\d` matches only digits; `\w` matches any alphanumeric character.

[Python Regular Expression HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) by A.M. Kuchling.